# Making the ::before pseudo element overlay the containing element for an anchor tag?

Tags: html, css

Trying to get the `::before` pseudo element of the `a` tag to overlay the `div` element completely.  Below is a demo of what I have so far.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
}
a {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

div a::before {
  display: block;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: black;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
    <div
      style="
        background-color: yellow;
        position: relative;
        width: 300px;
        height: 50px;
      "
    >
      stuff
      <a style="width: 100%; height: 100%"> </a>
    </div>
```

I thought this CSS should have done the trick, but no love.  Any ideas?

```
    div a::before {
      z-index: 1000;
      background-color: black;
      pointer-events: none;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
    }
```

Comment: hi, I'm not sure what you mean by 'overlay', and why you have repeating inline and external style (inside your html tags and in a css sheet), but you lack an instruction in your css for the ::before pseudo element, the `content: '';` : 'If the content property is not specified, has an invalid value, or has normal or none as a value, then the ::before pseudo-element is not rendered' (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before). I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks hugogog!!  I almost never use the `::before` element, so I totally forgot about the `content` property!  Thanks again!!

Comment: glad it helped :) also, for it to work you don't need the z-index (in your example provided, at least)